# How to create a binary column based on specific text in another column in R?

Tags: r

I'm working in R and I need to create a binary column based on whether the player has the name Mike (0 for No, 1 for Yes). This is the code I have so far, but I don't know what to do next:

```
baseball$player_mike <- ifelse(baseball$player_name == "%Mike%", 1, 0)
```

`baseball` is the data frame, `player_mike` is what the binary column would be, and `player_name` is the list of players (has their full name). Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `baseball$player_mike <- as.numeric(grepl("Mike", baseball$player_name))`

Comment: The `%` signs have no specific meaning in R, unlike SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional `tidyverse` approach to things, since you first worked with `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)
output <- baseball %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    player_mike = ifelse(player_name == "Mike", 1, 0)
  )
```

If you have instances of `mike` as well as `Mike`, you can do `tolower(player_name)` to accommodate for that.

Answer (score 0):

a `data.table` alternative:

```
require(data.table) # loads library

setDT(baseball) # sets baseball as a data.table

baseball[, player_mike := 0L] # creates a column and assigns 0 to all its values

baseball[grepl("Mike", player_name, ignore.case = TRUE), player_mike := 1L] 
       # filters rows where "Mike" appears in the player_name and 
       # assigns 1 to player_mike of those rows
```